# Accessing iframe through console using DOM and BOM in JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I've been playing around with DOM and BOM in JavaScript through Google Chrome's console trying to change locally input values, colors, etc...on different websites. I stumbled on a website that used iframe tags for it's form. I tried to change the value of the inputs located inside the iframe but couldn't get it done. My understanding is iframe incorporates a separate webpage inside of the one currently viewed.

My question is simple how do I access the tags inside of the iframe?

Things I tried so far:

```
document.getElementById("")
document.getElementsByTagNames("")
window.frames
window.parent
```

Comment: Accessing content of an iframe by console is not the same as access from a page. Same Origin Policy  restricts access from a page but not console. Try using `var content = document.querySelector('iframe').contentWindow`

Answer (score 0):

So an iframe is an inline frame, and what that inline frame contains is the building blocks to build a website, or display someone elses website. If you know DOM traversal you would basically have to select that iframe, and then go to select the DOM objects within that iframe from there to manipulate those.

```
iframe = $('#myId');
iframe.contents().find('htmlelements');
```

Here is a sandbox environment to begin understanding the traversal portion:
    http://jsfiddle.net/fDFca/

Comment: i tried it i get this error `Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementById(...).contents is not a function
    at <anonymous>:1:40`

Comment: I apologise I was using jQuery there. Try contentWindow instead of contents. I imagine you will need something other than find as well as thats probably jQuery as well.